# Why does subproject not compile after migrating from 2.2 to 2.3?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

I switched to Play Framework 2.3 and now having an error, that my sub projects, on which my project is depending on, are not compiled anymore.

This is my `Build.scala` file:

```
val main = Project(appName, file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala).settings(
    version := appVersion,
    scalaVersion := "2.10.4",
    libraryDependencies += jdbc,
    libraryDependencies += cache,
    slickCodeGen <<= slickCodeGenTask,
    sourceGenerators in Compile <+= slickCodeGenTask 
).dependsOn(dbGen)
```

When I `run` or `compile` my project, the `target/scala-2.10` remains empty. Even if I try compiling the sub project explicitly via command line (`project dbGen` and then `compile`), same result. When compiling my main project, I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`, since my sub project wasn't compiled.

It worked all fine with Play 2.2. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you do `about` and then `projects` when in sbt shell? Could you post the info's from the output of `compile`? That would help to narrow it down.

Comment: If you do a project dbGen do you go to the dbGen project? Can you compile it from there?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
val main = ...
```

to

```
lazy val main = ...
```

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html

[Play 2.3 subproject dependsOn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391877/play-2-3-subproject-dependson?rq=1)