# Play 2.3 subproject dependsOn

Tags: playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

This is how I configure the subprojects at Play 2.3. However, it gives me sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency. What is wrong with my settings? This works in 2.2.

```
    val model = Project(appName + "-model", file("models")).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala).settings(
      version := appVersion,
      libraryDependencies ++= modelDependencies          
    )

    val main = Project(appName, file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala).enablePlugins(SbtWeb).settings(
      version := appVersion,
      libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies
    ).dependsOn(model % "test->test;compile->compile")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
  lazy val model = Project(
    id = s"${appName}-model", 
    base = file("models"))
    .enablePlugins(play.PlayScala)
    .settings(version := appVersion)
    .settings(scalaVersion := "2.11.1" )
    .settings(libraryDependencies ++= modelDependencies)

  lazy val main = Project(
    id = appName,
    base = file("webapp"))
    .enablePlugins(play.PlayScala)
    .enablePlugins(SbtWeb)
    .settings(name := "play-scala")
    .settings(version := appVersion)
    .settings(scalaVersion := "2.11.1" )
    .settings(libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies)
    .dependsOn(model % "test->test;compile->compile")

  override def rootProject = Some(main)
```